# XSLT Grouping for Name Directory

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, grouping, muenchian-grouping

I am trying to build a Last Name directory for a project I am working on using XSLT. This is what I want to look like in the end. I want the XSLT to pick up the index grouping for the section search by where it displays the first letter of the person's last name and also, I want it to group by each section in the results based on the person's first letter of their last name.

Please see sample below.

---

Search by: A C F G J

A

Anderson
Andrews
Allison

C

Charles

F

Fredericks
Franks

G

Garrett

J

Johnson
James

I have tried the Muenchian grouping for the section to get the first initial of the person's last name to be under the appropriate letter (ie Section A Anderson, Andrews, Allison....J Johnson James) and that works fine.

Using this same code, I tried to apply it to the section to generate Search By A C F G J, where I want to show the first letter of the person's last name based on data from the XML. When tried the code, I didn't get any results back for this section.

Can someone please help with this?
Thanks

Cheers

---

**UPDATE**

The OP wishes to transform this input document ...

```
<people>
 <person><lastname>Johnson</lastname></person>
 <person><lastname>James</lastname></person>
 <person><lastname>Charles</lastname></person>
 <person><lastname>Franks</lastname></person>
 <person><lastname>Anderson</lastname></person>
 <person><lastname>Allison</lastname></person>
 <person><lastname>Fredericks</lastname></person>
 <person><lastname>Andrews</lastname></person>
</people>
```

... into the text formatted output document shown above, using XSLT. It is not clear if the OP is using XSLT 1.0 or 2.0. The search letters are provided to the style-sheet as a style-sheet parameter formatted as a space-separated list of uppercase letters, declared like so ...

```
<xsl:param name="search-by" select="'A C F G J'" />
```

You can assume that these letters are already sorted alphabetically and are restricted to uppercase.

Comment: <person>
  <lastname>Johnson</lastname>
</person>
<person>
  <lastname>James</lastname>
</person>
<person>
  <lastname>Charles</lastname>
</person>
<person>
  <lastname>Franks</lastname>
</person>
<person>
  <lastname>Anderson</lastname>
</person>
<person>
  <lastname>Allison</lastname>
</person>
<person>
  <lastname>Fredericks</lastname>
</person>
<person>
  <lastname>Andrews</lastname>
</person>

Comment: 1) What have you tried? People will help but not just do it for you outright. 2) What is the meaning behind your appended comment? Please edit the question where necessary rather than fixing it with comments.

Comment: Hi
1) I have tried the Muenchian method for the groupings and can get the last names to show up under the appropriate letter by using substring(lastname, 1, 1). Taking that same code that I used, I want to build another section that just shows A C F G J but that doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

If you are supplying the sort-by letters by parameter, then muenchian grouping is not required.

This XSLT 1.0 style-sheet ...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text" />
<xsl:param name="search-by" select="'A C F G J'" />

<xsl:key name="section" match="person" use="substring( lastname, 1, 1)" />

<xsl:template match="/">
Search by: <xsl:value-of select="$search-by" /><xsl:value-of select="'&#x0A;&#x0A;'" />   
  <xsl:call-template name="do-section">
    <xsl:with-param name="sections" select="$search-by" /> 
  </xsl:call-template>  
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="do-section">
 <xsl:param name="sections" />
 <xsl:if test="$sections != ''" > 
  <xsl:variable name="letter" select="substring($sections,1,1)" />
  <xsl:value-of select="concat( $letter, '&#x0A;&#x0A;')" />
  <xsl:for-each select="key('section',$letter)">
   <xsl:sort data-type="text" /> 
   <xsl:value-of select="concat( lastname, '&#x0A;')" />   
  </xsl:for-each>   
  <xsl:value-of select="'&#x0A;'" />   
  <xsl:call-template name="do-section">
    <xsl:with-param name="sections" select="substring($sections,3)" /> 
  </xsl:call-template>  
 </xsl:if> 
</xsl:template>  

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

... applied with input style-sheet parameter $search-by='A C F G J' and applied to this input document ...

```
<people>
 <person><lastname>Johnson</lastname></person>
 <person><lastname>James</lastname></person>
 <person><lastname>Charles</lastname></person>
 <person><lastname>Franks</lastname></person>
 <person><lastname>Anderson</lastname></person>
 <person><lastname>Allison</lastname></person>
 <person><lastname>Fredericks</lastname></person>
 <person><lastname>Andrews</lastname></person>
</people>
```

... produces this text document ...

```
Search by: A C F G J

A

Allison
Anderson
Andrews

C

Charles

F

Franks
Fredericks

G


J

James
Johnson
```